# Error in unnest(.) : could not find function "unnest"

Tags: r

hola lo que pasa es que cuando intento hacer la practica me aparece este error y solo me dijeron {no veo donde se invoca la función} queria saber que puedo hacer para que no me marque el error. se los agradeceria mucho
cualquier solución me serviria. (: ))

```
tweets_tidy <- tweets1 %>% select(-texto) %>% unnest()
```

este es el completo

```html
# ---------------------------------------------------
# Practica 1 - Análisis exploratorio:
# 1) Al tokenizar, el elemento de estudio ha pasado a 
# ser cada token, incumpliendo así la condición de tidy data. 
tweets_tidy <- tweets1 %>% select(-texto) %>% unnest()
tweets_tidy <- tweets_tidy %>% rename(token = texto_tokenizado)
head(tweets_tidy) 
# 2) Crear una gráfica de la distribución de los tweets 
# recuperados en función de la fecha en que fueron publicados
ggplot(tweets1, aes(x = as.Date(fecha), fill = autor)) +
 geom_histogram(position = "identity", bins = 20, show.legend = FALSE) +
 scale_x_date(date_labels = "%m-%Y", date_breaks = "2 week") +
 labs(x = "fecha de publicación", y = "número de tweets") +
 facet_wrap(~ autor, ncol = 1) + theme_bw() + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
tweets_mes_anyo <- tweets1 %>% mutate(mes_anyo = format(fecha, "%Y-%m"))
tweets_mes_anyo %>% group_by(autor, mes_anyo) %>% summarise(n = n()) %>% ggplot(aes(x = mes_anyo, y = n, color 
= autor)) +
 geom_line(aes(group = autor)) +
 labs(title = "Número de tweets publicados", x = "fecha de publicación",
 y = "número de tweets") + theme_bw() +
 theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, size = 6),
 legend.position = "bottom")
# 3) Conteo de palabras por usuario: 
tweets_tidy %>% group_by(autor) %>% summarise(n = n()) 
tweets_tidy %>% ggplot(aes(x = autor)) + geom_bar() + coord_flip() + theme_bw()
# 4) onteo de palabras distintas por usuario:
tweets_tidy %>% select(autor, token) %>% distinct() %>% group_by(autor) %>% summarise(palabras_distintas = n()) 
tweets_tidy %>% select(autor, token) %>% distinct() %>%
 ggplot(aes(x = autor)) + geom_bar() + coord_flip() + theme_bw()
# 8) Relación entre palabras (limpieza de tweets)
limpiar <- function(texto){
# Se convierte todo el texto a minúsculas
 nuevo_texto <- tolower(texto)
 
 # Eliminación de páginas web (palabras que empiezan por "http." seguidas 
 # de cualquier cosa que no sea un espacio)
 nuevo_texto <- str_replace_all(nuevo_texto,"http\\S*", "")
 # Eliminación de signos de puntuación
 nuevo_texto <- str_replace_all(nuevo_texto,"[[:punct:]]", " ")
 # Eliminación de números
 nuevo_texto <- str_replace_all(nuevo_texto,"[[:digit:]]", " ")
 # Eliminación de espacios en blanco múltiples
 nuevo_texto <- str_replace_all(nuevo_texto,"[\\s]+", " ")
 return(nuevo_texto)
}
# 9) Stopwords (palabras que no aportan al texto)
require(sm)
lista_stopwords <- stopwords("spanish")
# Se añade el término amp al listado de stopwords
lista_stopwords <- c(lista_stopwords, "amp")
# Se filtran las stopwords
tweets_tidy <- tweets_tidy %>% filter(!(token %in% lista_stopwords))
#5) Correlación entre usuarios por palabras utilizadas:
tweets_spread <- tweets_tidy %>% group_by(autor, token) %>% count(token) %>%
 spread(key = autor, value = n, fill = NA, drop = TRUE)
cor.test(~ franco_esca + MYMALK4PON3, method = "pearson", data = tweets_spread)
p1 <- ggplot(tweets_spread, aes(franco_esca, LuisitoComunica)) + geom_jitter(alpha = 0.1, size = 2.5, width = 0.25, 
height = 0.25) + geom_text(aes(label = token), check_overlap = TRUE, vjust = 1.5) + 
 scale_x_log10(labels = percent_format()) + scale_y_log10(labels = percent_format()) +
 geom_abline(color = "red") + theme_bw() + theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
 axis.text.y = element_blank())
p2 <- ggplot(tweets_spread, aes(MYMALK4PON3, LuisitoComunica)) + geom_jitter(alpha = 0.1, size = 2.5, width = 0.25, 
height = 0.25) + geom_text(aes(label = token), check_overlap = TRUE, vjust = 1.5) + 
 scale_x_log10(labels = percent_format()) + scale_y_log10(labels = percent_format()) +
 geom_abline(color = "red") + theme_bw() + theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
 axis.text.y = element_blank())
grid.arrange(p1, p2, nrow = 1)
# 6) Conteo de palabras comunes entre dos usuarios: 
palabras_comunes <- dplyr::intersect(tweets_tidy %>% filter(autor=="LuisitoComunica") %>%
 select(token), tweets_tidy %>% filter(autor=="franco_esca") %>%
 select(token)) %>% nrow()

paste("Número de palabras comunes entre LuisitoComunica y franco_esca", palabras_comunes)

palabras_comunes <- dplyr::intersect(tweets_tidy %>% filter(autor=="LuisitoComunica") %>%
 select(token), tweets_tidy %>% filter(autor=="MYMALK4PON3") %>%
 select(token)) %>% nrow()
paste("Número de palabras comunes entre LuisitoComunica y MYMALK4PON3", palabras_comunes)
# 7) Comparación en el uso de palabras:
# a) Pivotaje y despivotaje
tweets_spread <- tweets_tidy %>% group_by(autor, token) %>% count(token) %>% spread(key = autor, value = n, fill = 0, 
drop = TRUE)
tweets_unpivot <- tweets_spread %>% gather(key = "autor", value = "n", -token)
# b) Selección de los autores LuisitoComunica y franco_esca
tweets_unpivot <- tweets_unpivot %>% 
filter(autor %in% c("franco_esca", "LuisitoComunica"))
# c) Se añade el total de palabras de cada autor
tweets_unpivot <- tweets_unpivot %>% left_join(tweets_tidy %>% group_by(autor) %>%summarise(N = n()), by = 
"autor")
tweets_unpivot
# d) Cálculo de odds y log of odds de cada palabra
tweets_logOdds <- tweets_unpivot %>% mutate(odds = (n + 1) / (N + 1))
tweets_logOdds <- tweets_logOdds %>% select(autor, token, odds) %>% spread(key = autor, value = odds)
tweets_logOdds <- tweets_logOdds %>% mutate(log_odds = log(franco_esca/MYMALK4PON3), abs_log_odds = 
abs(log_odds))
tweets_logOdds <- tweets_logOdds %>% mutate(autor_frecuente = if_else(log_odds > 0, "@franco_esca", 
"@MYMALK4PON3"))
tweets_logOdds %>% arrange(desc(abs_log_odds)) %>% head() 
a <- tweets_logOdds %>% group_by(autor_frecuente) %>% top_n(15, abs_log_odds)
# f) Graficar resultados
ggplot(a,aes(x = reorder(token, log_odds), y = log_odds, fill = autor_frecuente)) + 
geom_col() + labs(x = "palabra", y = "log odds ratio (franco_esca / MYMALK4PON3)") + coord_flip() + theme_bw()
#Representación gráfica de las frecuencias
tweets_tidy %>% group_by(autor, token) %>% count(token) %>% group_by(autor) %>%
 top_n(10, n) %>% arrange(autor, desc(n)) %>%
 ggplot(aes(x = reorder(token,n), y = n, fill = autor)) +
 geom_col() +
 theme_bw() +
 labs(y = "", x = "") +
 theme(legend.position = "none") +
 coord_flip() +
 facet_wrap(~autor,scales = "free", ncol = 1, drop = TRUE)
```

Comment: El error `could not find function “unnest”` es bastante claro, R no encuentra la función `unnest()`, lo cual seguramente se debe a que no has cargado la librería de la función: `library(tidyr)`  aunque por todo el código que tienes tal vez es más apropiado cargar directamente `library(tidyverse)`

Comment: package �tidyr� was built under R version 4.0.5`cols` is now required when using unnest().
Please use `cols = c(texto_tokenizado)`Error in ggplot(tweets1, aes(x = as.Date(fecha), fill = autor)) : 
  could not find function "ggplot"

Comment: hola ahora me dice esto:

Comment: Sigues con un problema similar, las funciones como `unnest` o `ggplot` no foman parte de R base, necesitas cargar la librería que define esa funcionalidad, como te había dicho antes, prueba cargar directamente `library(tidyverse)` que es un metapaquete que carga entre otras,  `tidyr` y `ggplot`

Comment: otra cosa enserio muchas gracias ya vi que tenia que poner las librerias pero ahora me marca errror aqui:

Comment: Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `log_odds`. x object 'lenaychantelle' not found i Input `log_odds` is `log(GermanGarmendia/lenaychantelle)`. i The error occurred in group 1: token = "\U0001f1e8\U0001f1f1". Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error

Comment: tweets_logOdds <- tweets_logOdds %>% mutate(log_odds = log(GermanGarmendia/lenaychantelle), abs_log_odds = 
abs(log_odds))